# Custom (text) overlay on google map via KML

Tags: google-maps, kml

Is it possible to draw a custom text overlay on a google map via a kml file. I'm drawing several polygons (e.g. linear ring) that separate a region into districts and I want to indicate what district the polygon is and without an marker pin.

Answer (score 1):

KML does not have a native way to draw text or fonts directly on the map.

Your options include:

- Add a Point/Placemark with a Label at the center of your polygon. In the IconStyle, set scale to zero, so that you only see the label.
- Use a GroundOverlay image that contains the text and has a transparent background
- Find a way to generate KML lines or polygons in the shape of your letters/text, and place those on the map.